# WPF Business Object

Tags: c#, wpf, business-objects

first of all, I have read a lot of articles (and questions) here and all over the internet about WPF and Business Object but I'm not sure what I have to do to create one with validation yet.
Since I'm new to WPF, I'm having a bad time understanding what need to be done to achieve this:
I have a B.O class which I need to integrate with WPF and edit, add, delete data without screwing up the data.

So, can someone clarify this to me with explanations or a good article ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You're afraid of `screwing up the data` - what do you mean by that? As for articles, if I were you, I'd read up on the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern. You are, however, saying that you've already read "a lot of articles" - it's therefore hard to give you advice or recommendations if you don't specify which aspect still escapes your understanding.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. By screwing up the data, I mean sending info to the B.O that are not consistent. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could try implementing the `IEditableObject` interface. This gives you a consistent way to implement **adding** data and **edit** them for changes (or the **rollback** of changes) on the object's data.

Have a look at this article *[IEditableObject Adapter for WPF and Windows Forms](http://www.paulstovell.com/editable-object-adapter) by Paul Stovell*.

> `IEditableObject` requires you to implement the following methods:
>
> ```
> BeginEdit()
> CancelEdit()
> EndEdit()
> ```

The interface is for:

> **BeginEdit** can be called manually, or in the case of the DataGridView,
>   it will be called automatically if implemented. This is the part where
>   you normally take your "snapshot" of the object's state. **CancelEdit** is
>   then called to rollback the changes, and **EndEdit** to accept them.

[EDIT]

As for the **validation** part within WPF applications, depending on what exactly you are trying to do, it might come in handy to use the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in your ViewModel.

Here is a helping tutorial on Code Project: [Validating User Input - WPF MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM)

> By implementing this interface in your models, combined with WPF data
>   binding, user input validation becomes automatic, and implementing
>   validation becomes merely a choice of how to present the validation
>   errors to the user. When working with the MVVM design pattern, the
>   interface makes it easy to keep code out of your code behind and in
>   your ViewModel and Model.

Comment: I'll give it a try in a moment, then I'll post my feedback ! Thanks for the clear explanation Jens.

Comment: Hey man, I downloaded the example Paul provided, but I don't know how to bind his code to WPF. In his site (and demo) he shows how to use his code with Forms, but not with WPF. Do you have any idea how can I use that ? Thanks